# changing the line-height of an individual li tag

Tags: html, css

I want to have the phone number and email address vertically align with the little icons next to them. I'm trying to change their line-height, but that changes the line height of all the `li`'s in that area. I think that is because they are inline. Here is the site and the css.

**LINK:** [www.matthewtbrown.com/newsite](http://www.matthewtbrown.com/newsite)

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="contact"> 
    <li><img src="http://s7.postimg.org/64ux9a1if/email.png"></li>
    <li class="contacttext">mbrown74@rocketmail.com</li>
    <li><img src="http://s7.postimg.org/g0w08x7af/phone.png"></li>
    <li class="contacttext">978-761-1205</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
.contact {
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    float:none;
    }


.contact > li {
    display: inline;
    }

.contacttext {
    font-size: 19px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    }
```

Comment: You could use the image as the [`list-style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-image) instead of making separate `<li>` just for an image.

Answer (score 0):

That's where `vertical-align` comes into play which aligns inline elements to each other:

In your case the following should work:

```
.contacttext{
   vertical-align:text-top;
}
```

Also note, that if you want to have your `li` contain the `img` properly, it needs a display-type other than the default `inline` - `inline-block` might be suited most.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
li {
   display: inline;
   vertical-align: top;
   line-height: 25px;
}
```

after this i have this result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got it. I did:

```
.contacttext {
    font-size: 19px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    display:inline-block; 
    vertical-align:middle;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<ul class="contact">
<li class="contacttext">
    <img src="http://s7.postimg.org/64ux9a1if/email.png">mbrown74@rocketmail.com
</li>
<li class="contacttext">
    <img src="http://s7.postimg.org/g0w08x7af/phone.png">978-761-1205
</li>
```

I just kept the icons and the text in the same li's

Answer (score -1):

You could add `margin-bottom` to your `<img>` to solve this issue.

```
li img {
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}
```